# polymorphic static and non-static functions in PHP

Tags: php, polymorphism, static-methods

I wanted to make a simple `Path` class in PHP. I decided to use some polymorphic-like mechanisms for implementing it, but I found no way to do it for both: static and non-static functions. Do you have any ideas how to implement the `absolute()` function in an elegant way?

```
class Path {

    private $path = '';

    // Some code here [...]

    public function absoulte() {
        return "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$this->path";
    }

    public static function absoulte($path) {
        return "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$path";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, to not implement the same function twice, you could create an instance and call the non-static function on it: `public static function absolute($path) { return (new static($path))->absolute(); }` (expecting there to be a constructor that accepts the path as only variable)

Comment: @Namoshek, Sounds interesting, but I do not get the idea. How to create both functions with the same name? I am new to PHP, could you please explain it a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll give it a try and you see if it is helpful for you. :)

I think there is actually quite a few ways to implement a public interface like described by you, although they seem all rather complex to code and maintain. Therefore my advice would be to not go down this path if not really necessary. I will give some examples anway...

---

#### Possible Solution 1: usage of `__call` and `__callStatic`

We can simply use `__call` and `__callStatic` as proxy for our method and call the actual method with slightly different parameters. The PhpDoc on top should support the IDE in understanding what is going on here.

```
/**
 * @method string absolute()
 * @method static string absolute(string $path)
 */
class Path
{
    protected $path;

    public function __construct(string $path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    public function __call(string $name, array $args)
    {
        if ($name === 'absolute') {
            return self::getAbsolutePath($this->path);
        }

        // ... other functions ...
    }

    public function __callStatic(string $name, array $args)
    {
        if ($name === 'absolute' && count($args) >= 1) {
            return self::getAbsolutePath($args[0]);
        }

        // ... other functions ...
    }

    private static function getAbsolutePath(string $path): string
    {
        return "http://{$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]}{$path}";
    }
}
```

#### Possible Solution 2: react to execution environment

Because we can access methods in PHP both in a static manner as well as in a non-static manner, we simply use the information to our hands to return the proper result.

```
/**
 * @method string absolute()
 * @method static string absolute(string $path)
 */
class Path
{
    protected $path;

    public function __construct(string $path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    public function absolute(?string $path): string
    {
        if (isset($this) && $this instanceof self) {
            $path = $this->path;
        }

        return "http://{$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]}{$path}";
    }
}
```

#### Other Solutions

I think there are also other ways to implement this, probably with making use of a proxy class or so. But the correct way of doing it does also depend on other requirements than what we saw until now. Because one parameter `$path` is quite easy to deal with, but the more complex your class gets, the more work it will be to implement the different scenarios.

To conclude I want to pick up on my comment above: try to not implement things twice if there is a way around it. You'll find yourself in situations later where you are hunting bugs in multiple places. So it is probably the best idea to just have two different interfaces with a common implementation. It can actually even make sense, because the same method name doesn't necessarily make sense in both a static as well as a non-static environment. So consider using something like this:

```
/**
 * @method string absolute()
 * @method static string absolute(string $path)
 */
class Path
{
    protected $path;

    public function __construct(string $path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath(): string
    {
        return self::absolute($this->path);
    }

    public static function absolute(string $path): string
    {
        return "http://{$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]}{$path}";
    }
}
```

Comment: It helped me a lot! Thank you! You explained to me all the things I never know about PHP :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with "__callStatic". It will trigger if you call any static function on this class. "$name" gonna be the method name and "$arguments" is any argument passed. :D

```
class Path {

    private $path = '';

    // Some code here [...]

    public function absoulte() {
        return "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$this->path";
    }

   public static function __callStatic($name,$arguments) {
       if ($name == "absoulte") {  return "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$arguments"; }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is already solved, but maybe will help someone else. Here is another approach using `func_num_args()` and `func_get_arg()` functions which works as well.

```
class Path {

    private $path = '';

    // ...

    public function absolute() {
        switch (func_num_args()) {
            case 0: return "http://" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $this->path;
            case 1: return "http://" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . func_get_arg(0);
            default: trigger_error("Invalid number of arguments", E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```